# preg_replace %{Variable} with $variable

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am trying to replace a server variable in RewriteCondition with php variable.

forexampe :

I have the following string :

```
$x="RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www";
```

I want to replace %{VAR} with $var==

```
 $x="RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www";
preg_replace("/%\{[^}]+)\}/i","$$1==",$x);
```

The code above is not working, I am getting a warning from php regex parser :

```
compilation failed, unmatched parentheses at offset at
```

I tried to escape $ in the replacement with a backslash, but it also didn't solve the issue.

Is there something wrong with the function?

Comment: Did you try matching the parens?

Comment: `preg_replace("/\%\{[^\}]+\}/i","$$1==",$x)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message:

> Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: unmatched parentheses at offset 8

is correct. You have unmatched parentheses in your regex. The 8th character is `)` (https://eval.in/485179) but there is no `(`.

This

```
$x="RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www";
echo preg_replace("/%\{([^}]+)\}/","$$1==",$x);
```

would give you:

```
RewriteCond $HTTP_HOST== ^www
```

Here's a regex101 demo: https://regex101.com/r/yB0yQ5/2; and a PHP demo, https://eval.in/485180.

The `i` modifier also didn't make sense here since your regex had no alpha characters in it. You could add that back in if you plan to have those in the future.